# glib man pages not available for 2.47.5

Tags: c, documentation, glib

I was wondering whether glib has any specific man pages available. It does have a comprehensive reference manual, but it would be a lot easier if some man pages were available online. 
Another possible option would be to parse the html pages and generate the man pages accordingly, but that would require some hacking to do.
reference manual link
https://developer.gnome.org/glib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a project a while back which let you generate man pages from the XML format used by gtk-doc: https://github.com/chergert/gnome-manpages

TBH, you're probably better off either using developer.gnome.org (each manual has an [index](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/api-index-full.html) which is very helpful if you want to find a symbol) or, if you want a local copy, [Devhelp](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Devhelp) (you'll probably need to install the documentation package for your distro of choice).